# How to implement Inner Join on Realm DB in android

Tags: android, realm

I am searching everywhere but not found the exact way to use Inner Join on **Realm DB** in Android, check my code

```
public class UserName extends RealmObject {

    private int UserID;
    private String UserName;
    
    // Getter Setters
}

public class UserDepartment extends RealmObject {

    private int UserID;
    private String UserDepartment;
    
    // Getter Setters
}
```

In SQLite by using following query we easily get data

```
Select n.UserName, d.UserDepartment 
FROM Name n INNER JOIN Department d
ON n.UserID=d.UserID 
ORDER BY d.UserDepartment
```

But how to do same thing on Realm DB to get result...

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: by looking here :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628574/implementing-a-form-of-join-query-on-a-realm-db-without-having-a-predefined-rela

its not possible

Comment: Hi @YakirMalka, not by using query but is their something to do the same?

Answer (score 1):

As you may know Realm is a non-relational database and concepts like join belongs for relational database. but if you need to have both `UserName` and `UserDepartment` in a single model class there are lots of implementations. but due to my experiences and according to realm constraints in using objects on different threads and updating objects snapshot with realm file, I suggest you to create a new entity, just like this:

```
class User extends RealmObject{
   private int userId;
   private UserName username;
   private UserDepartment userDepartment;
}
```

whenever you insert a record into either `UserName` or `UserDepartment` you need to insert a record or update existing record in `User`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you mean that for every relationship in tables(entities) we have to make new table(entity)??

Comment: @piyushpk No, it depends to your need. Also there are alternative solutions. But the main notion in designing your db is: you should avoid thinking like relational pattern.I suggest you to study about NoSql world this would help you to avoid such problems.